# Cannot find out to install iwlwifi. no way to find out what kernel has to do with it

Tags: iwlwifi

I've ran commands but "no command found" is what I get every time. I've downloaded iwlwifi from Intel but the directions are useless. Every command I try says "command not found". Sorry if i seem helpless but I've gotten nowhere. Ethernet doesn't seem to work besides browsers. Please I need some command that works with iwlwifi 59 or some solution to find wifi.

Comment: The question is totally unclear. Why are you thinking you need to install `iwlwifi`. It is installed already. Are you using Ubuntu? What is the actual problem? Ethernet is a wired network protocol and is unrelated to `iwlwifi`. Please [edit] your question and make it more clear. Please explain the real problem including OS/release details and hardware used.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting